# @hotwired/turbo-rails / infinite loop that crash the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

Trying out turborails; given this super simple config :

```
# posts/index.html.erb
<%= turbo_stream_from("posts") %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "posts" do %>
  <%= render posts %>
<% end %>

# posts/_post.html.erb
<%= turbo_stream_from(post) %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(post) do %>
  <%= post.label %>
<% end %>

# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  broadcasts
end
```

We want to refresh the list when a new post is added.
When updating a given post, we want it to refresh within the list.

Everythings works smoothly at the beginning, we're getting what we want. Then, navigating, coming back to the page, things starts to get super ugly; the backend loops the following infinitely :

```
 [ActionCable] [5e298b47-2a81-4770-9afb-07be06991d62] Ignoring message processed after the WebSocket was closed: "{\"command\":\"subscribe\",\"identifier\":\"{\\\"channel\\\":\\\"Turbo::StreamsChannel\\\",\\\"signed_stream_name\\\":\\\"IloybGtPaTh2WkcxNEwwVjBiRG82VkhKaGJuTm1aWEl2TXpnMVlqRmxOMkl0TVdWaE1pMDBZakppTFRnMk5qUXRZbVUwT1RWbVl6bGhOVGxpIg==--69b574f5584e2cfcfbf1d59d692f4cea40ce0d730d7794e3dac523cd609006a3\\\"}\"}")
```

and at some point, the browser crashes.

The might be something obvious to fix in our config; at least looking for help to find out what to do

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused this?

Comment: I am also wondering if you found the solution in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still verifying the fix in my own app, but I suspect it's because you're subscribing to the `post` turbo stream every time the partial is replaced/re-rendered.  For you, it might make more sense to use the model `after_commit` hooks, etc.

I've moved my equivalent subscribe line out to the main file (index in your case) and haven't been able to reproduce the issue since.  As I said, I still want to do more testing to verify.

My setup is a bit different than yours in that I'm not rendering using a collection.  Here's my code:

```
# index.html.erb
<%= turbo_stream_from "items_#{@item.id}" %>
<%= turbo_stream_from "progress_for_#{@item.id}" %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "prefix_#{dom_id(@item)}" do %>
    <%= render partial: "prequalification_shared/progress_bar", locals: {progress: @progress, item: @item} %>
    <% end %>
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>

# _progress_bar.html.erb
<%# commented this out #= turbo_stream_from "progress_for_#{item.id}" %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(item, :progress), class: "prequal-progress-bar-container" do %>
  <div>
    <div style="width: <%= progress %>%"></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```